# Are there any mosquitto performance test tools which support the TLS Pre-shared key protocol?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I want to do some performance tests with mosquitto using the TLS Pre-shared key protocol. Are there any existing tools that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at [mqtt malaria](https://github.com/remakeelectric/mqtt-malaria)

It isn't perhaps exactly what you want, but definitely supports TLS-PSK through the use of multiple mosquitto instances bridging to a central broker under test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had looked at mqtt malaria. But it seems it not support PSK. I got below comments from mqtt malaria source code "PSK is only supported with bridging due to python limitations, sorry about that".  Any ideas about this?

Comment: Right, Python doesn't support TLS-PSK so the idea is to use lots of mosquitto brokers bridging to the broker under test, each of them using TLS-PSK.

Comment: Glad the solution is helpful. Would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people experiencing a similar issue and will help getting your question noticed. For more information, take a look at our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thanks and welcome to SO!